# What sections should a high quality Bug report contain?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, bug-report, defect-tracking, test-report

I am a newbie in testing and i just write in the bug report, the pre-requisites , actual results and expected result section under "description".

Other testers say that my report is not professional and it's incomplete.

How can I improve my verbiage in expected results. Is it like - "user should be deleted on clicking delete button ' or "user is or must be deleted?

How to write a high quality bug? Refer to a sample bug report written by  testing experts.

Comment: Welcome. This question is asked many times: just look around here (or Google). As there is not a "best report" I would suggest asking your co-workers on what they expect. You are a newbie, so they should understand that you are _by definition_ inexperienced. I can advice this, however: [bug advocacy by Cem Kaner](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/bugadvocacy/)

Comment: Also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/1920/8992

Comment: and https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/6168/8992

Comment: Or search [Bug report](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=bug+report) ;-)

Comment: For writing a good defect, the first and foremost important thing is the summary (which should be precise and up to the mark).

A good defect needs below components: 

1. Summary :- States what actually the defect/issue is.
2. Description:- It should contain the following:
  a. Environment Details: ( Where the defect is being tested i.e. on iOS, Android or Web )
  b. Browser Details: (If any)

Than, we move on to 
c. Pre-requisite 
d. Steps to Reproduce 
e. Actual Result 
f. Expected Result
g. Whats Working/Whats Not Working (describe the areas where the issue is working or not)